In vb.net , upload file to API
I need to build an API to accept file and I need to pass the file as parameter wrapped in class.
I could pass file and save the file in server with below code:
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function UploadDataCheckFile() As IHttpActionResult

  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Item(0))

end function 

I tested the above code with Postman and it works
but I need to pass the parameter wrapped in class; something like below:
Public Class DataCheckParam
    Public Property byteFile As HttpPostedFile
end class


<HttpPost()> _
Public Function UploadDataCheckFile(ByVal t As DataCheckParam) As IHttpActionResult
'when i try to debug the code, t is nothing here

end function 

When I try to run above code, I get this error:
"Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'DataCheckParam' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"


try DataCheckParam.byteFile

tried that. it did not work.

You need somewhere define upliadfile so that it exists,vin your code that you posted it is missing

Uploading file is done in client side. I have posted only api part of code to handle the uploaded file.

the clinet so send the file to the server and when all data is received you have a memorystream which you can handle, on client isde it is easy you get a filestream which you need to convert on the fly to bytes. i am not seeeing why you want a class for that at all

if more than one type of file with different key needs to sent to api, it'll be easier to handle and the code will be more readable. va;idations for the parameters can be done in that class.  I know there can be many work arounds, but is there a rule that we cant send the files wrapped in class? where can i find details regarding that?

no sending a class woll not be possible, but you can assign the received file in a class, as your operating does with recognizing the file endings
